# Set Rules on a Dropdown Values

Tags: infopath-rules

I have a dropdown containing five values i.e. A,B,C,D and E. I want to set constraint for only two particular values say 'C' & 'D'. i.e. Only 'D' can be selected, if 'C' was selected before. Or, if 'C' is selected from the dropdown, only 'D' can be selected next.

Can I achieve this using a variable(if so, please provide steps)? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: if one value is selected in one dropdown, how second value could be selected?. Are their two dropdowns? Please be clear.

Comment: There is only one dropdown. I need to set constraint like:
If C is selected presently, next only D can be selcted. If we select anything other than D, it should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with simple javascript.  Like the commenter before me said, it isn't exactly clear what you mean by what you want to do.  However, I will attempt to answer both ways you could mean.  Lets say your indexes are as such: A is at 0, B is at 1, C is at 2, and D is at 3.  Let's say you have two boxes, and when a user selects an option in box 1, it limits the options in box 2.  Here is the code for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideChoices() {
  var target_box_1 = document.getElementById("ID_of_box_1");  //find the ID of the Dropdown box in your web code
  var target_box_2 = document.getElementByID("ID_of_box_2");
  if(target_box_1.options[target_box_1.selectedIndex].value == "C") {  //Let's hide options A and B
      target_box_2.options[0].value = ''  //Sets select value to NULL for A
      target_box_2.options[0].innerHTML = ''  //Makes the option in the box blank for A
      target_box_2.options[1].value = ''  //Sets select value to NULL for B
      target_box_2.options[1].innerHTML = ''  //Makes the option in the box blank for B
   }
 }

 //Either attach script to DDbox, or include this function windows.onload = hideChoices();
</script>
```

For the other way you could mean, just switch target_box_2 with target_box_1.  This way would overwrite the values in the current drop box you are using.

Now, if what you mean is if they choose an option, then navigate away from the page, come back, and re-use a drop box, and their choices are limited by what they picked last time they picked an option, you will need to probably use CAML and Javascript, since you will need to either query your lists, or store that value in some variable.  Maybe you can have a  tag or area that prints what the user chose last time, and then use Javascript to simply read that choice, and use if statements in conjuncture with what I previously wrote.  If that didn't make sense, I can probably write some simple code for that as well.

Comment: There is only one dropdown. I need to set constraint like: If C is selected presently, next only D can be selcted. If we select anything other than D, it should throw an error. It is an info-path form.

Comment: Infopath can take Jscripts, can they not?  And I addressed that part in the second part of my giant text wall.  Just don't use a second text box, replace all target_box_2 with target_box_1, and get rid of target_box_2 all together.  If you want the options to be there still, but throw an error, Jscript includes try and catch.